# Refresh ListView from other SherlockFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm been trying for the last couple of hours to refresh a ListView from a different SherlockFragment. My code looks like this:

```
public class MealsFragment extends SherlockFragment {

   ............

   ............


   class ParseXMLData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     .......

     .......

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        populateMealsView();
       }

   }

}
```

On the MealsFragment class I'm calling the ParseXMLData class that does the heavy job and on the onPostExecute() function it populates a ListView. Until here everything is working great! The problem is the following: imagine I press a item of the ListView, a SherlockDialogFragment is created that contains several TextView and a Button. When the user presses that Button I want the **ParseXMLData AsyncTask** to be called again(NOT from the MealsFragment class), so the listview can be updated. The populateMealsView() looks like this:

```
public void populateMealsView() {
        //System.out.println("SIZE: " + meals.size());
        adapter.setItems(meals);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

How can I accomplish that? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either get a reference of the other class and just call the method that triggers your xml parser task, or you implement an Interface that starts the parser and you would implement a Central bus handling your events.

That way you can trigger an event where ever you are in your app.